# Using Shor's algorithm to solve the discrete logarithm problem

Tags: discrete-logarithm, shors-algorithm

I have read about Shor's algorithm and my understanding is that it can be used to factor large numbers efficiently. Can Shor's algorithm, though, be used to solve this problem:

Find the number $n$ given the following information (Assume that $g$, $n$, $P$ and $a$ are all large, say 2048-bit integers):

- the integers $g$ and $P$
- the integer $a$ where  $a = g^n \bmod P$

If so, how does this algorithm work? Please explain it simply as I am not familiar with quantum mechanics.

Comment: Actually, conventional computers can solve that problem reasonably easily if we're talking about 256 bit integers.  Conventional wisdom says that N needs to be at least 2048 bits to be secure against conventional computers (and it's not at all secure against a quantum one - if no one else answers, I'll spell it out when I get some time)

Comment: Relevant paper: [*"Polynomial-Time Algorithms for Prime Factorization and Discrete Logarithms on a Quantum Computer"* by Peter Shor](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027v2)

Answer (score 14):

Shor's method relies on a period finding routine on a quantum computer.

A function $f: (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is periodic, of period $(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n)$, if $f(x_1 + \omega_1, \dots, x_n + \omega_n) = f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ for all tuples $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ in the domain of $f$.

---

**Factorization problem**  Given an RSA modulus $N = pq$, find primes $p$ and $q$.

1. Choose a random integer $a \in \mathbb{Z}_N$ (without loss of generality, we assume $\gcd(a,N) = 1$ —otherwise, this yields the factorization of $N$ and the factorization problem is solved).
2. Consider the univariate function $f: x \mapsto f(x) = a^x \bmod N$.
3. The period finding routine finds an $\omega$ such that $f(x + \omega) = f(x)$.  As a consequence, $\omega$ is a multiple of the order of $a$ modulo $N$.  Indeed, one has $f(x+\omega) = f(x) \iff a^\omega \equiv 1 \pmod N$.

If $\omega$ is a multiple of $\lambda(N)$ —where $\lambda(N)$ denotes Carmichael's function, then Miller's algorithm yields the factorization of $N$.  Otherwise, repeat the process with another $a$, get the period $\omega_a$, and update $\omega$ as $\omega \gets \operatorname{lcm}(\omega, \omega_a)$, until $\omega$ is a multiple of $\lambda(N)$.

[ A description of Miller's algorithm can be found in *Cryptography: Theory and Practice* by Douglas Stinson, http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/~dstinson/CTAP.html ]

---

**Discrete log problem** Let $g$ be a generator of a group $\mathbb{G}$ of prime order $q$.  Given $y = g^k \in \mathbb{G}$, find the value of $k$.

1. Consider the bivariate function $f : (x_1, x_2) \mapsto g^{x_1} y^{x_2}$.
2. The period finding routine finds a pair $(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ such that $f(x_1 + \omega_1, x_2 + \omega_2) = f(x_1,x_2)$.
3. This implies: $g^{\omega_1} y^{\omega_2} = 1_{\mathbb{G}} \iff g^{\omega_1  + k\omega_2} = 1_{\mathbb{G}}$ and thus $\omega_1  + k\omega_2 \equiv 0$, or $k\omega_2 \equiv -\omega_1\pmod q$.
4. There are $q$ pairs $(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ which produce this result. If each result is equally likely, then there is only a $1/q$ probability that   $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\equiv (0,0)\pmod q$. On the $(q-1)/q$ probability that it is not zero, the solution to the discrete logarithm problem is then given by $k = -\omega_1/\omega_2 \bmod q$.