# Difficulty of Shor's algorithm in a Schnorr group as a function of the modulus

Tags: discrete-logarithm, group-theory, quantum-cryptanalysis, quantum-computing

Consider a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) with order a prime $q$ sized for security against current computers (like $q$ of 256 bit); modulus a prime $p=q\,r+1$ large enough (e.g. 3072 to 32768-bit) that the algorithms of choice for solving the DLP in the group are [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) or [Pollard's kangaroo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm), rather than [Index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm), [Function field sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_field_sieve) or [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).

The expected cost of breaking the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) in that group on classical computers is a few times $\sqrt q$ multiplications modulo $p$, thus grows about as $\log(p)^\alpha\sqrt q$ with some $\alpha$ depending on the algorithm ($\alpha\approx2$ for simple ones, $\alpha\approx\log_2(3)\approx1.585$ for [Karastuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), slightly lower $\alpha$ for more complex algorithms).

On an hypothetical Quantum Computuer, [Shor's algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027v2) in principle can be used for Discrete Logarithm problems (see answers to [these](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/103657/555) [questions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37018/555)), including for this group. How does the magnitude of $p$ influence the difficulty of doing this, by some useful criteria? Like number of qubits required, their quality (error rate? coherence time?), duration or energy required for the hypothetical computation.

---

My motivation is assessing if, when speed and key size are secondary, Schnorr Groups with moderate $q$ but large $p$ (by today's standards) would give some assurance of resisting an hypothetical first wave of [Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computers](https://crqc.grieu.fr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the magnitude of $p$ influence the difficulty of doing this, by some useful criteria?

Well, the expensive part of Shor's algorithm is the necessity of performing $O(\log q)$ multiplications (on entangled qubits) in the group (which, in this case, is mod $p$).

So, to do this would require $O(\log p)$ qubits, and (assuming you use the textbook multiplication algorithm) $O(\log q (\log p)^2)$ quantum operations.  So, increasing $p$ would increase both the required number of qubits and the total number of operations (but both by a low order polynomial factor).

Now, one suggestion I heard (by Shamir) was to instead do radically imbalanced RSA - we take a very large prime $p$ and a moderate prime $q$ (e.g. 1024 bits), and have our public key be $pq$ and a small exponent $e > \log p / \log q$; the private key is the value $q$ and $d = e^{-1} \bmod q-1$.  To encrypt a ciphertext $m$ (which is required to be less than $q$), we do the conventional encryption $c = m^e \bmod pq$.  To decrypt a ciphertext $c$, we first compute $c \bmod q$, and then compute $m = (c \bmod q)^d \bmod q$ (ignoring the $p$ part).  Here, encryption and decryption are both not that expensive, and to break the scheme, the only obvious approach is to factor $pq$ (which, because $p$ is large, might not be practical for first generation CRQC's).

I can't endorse this idea (because we have no idea how fast CRQC's will scale up) - however, it may perform better than your Schnorr group idea...

Comment: Shamir's unbalanced RSA approach is discussed among the trade-offs in the post-quantum RSA paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/351.pdf#page=11

Comment: I get that DLP in a Schnorr group is not quantum-resistant. Still, being able to raise the necessary number of qubits by a noticeable factor (like 10) and number of quantum operations (by even more) compared to ECC, at same signature size, seems a way to not be the first system to fail to hypothetical CRQC. I would call that quantum resilience.